# SwiftUI: ViewBuilder unable to create a collection of Views based on array

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to build a simple `List` by using `SwiftUI`. However, I am not able to dynamically create the rows by using an array of data. This is the error message: `Cannot convert value of type '(Setlist) -> SetlistRow' to expected argument type '(_) -> _'`

I've tried at least the following syntaxes, but I always get the same error.

- `List(setlists) { }`
- `List(setlists, rowContent: Setlist.init)`
- `ForEach(self.setlists) { setlist in }`

Here is my code:

```
struct Setlist {
    var name: String = "New setlist"
    var sets = [SongSet]()
}

struct SetlistManagerView : View {

    private var setlists: [Setlist] {
        // creates an array of dummy items
    }

    var body : some View {

        List {
            ForEach(setlists) {
                SetlistRow(setlist: $0)
            }
        }

    }
}

struct SetlistRow : View {

    var setlist: Setlist

    var body : some View {

        let numberOfSongs = setlist.sets.map { $0.songs.count }.reduce(0, +)

        return NavigationView {
            NavigationButton (destination: SetListView(setlist: setlist)) {
                // code for displaying the row
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the first example you're showing, make sure the objects conform to `Identifiable`, or just used `identified(by:)` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List items need to conform to `Identifiable` protocol in order for them to be used as collection data source without the `identified(by:)` argument.

Xcode error message here is misleading as the software is still in beta.